# Selenium Post method

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I'm trying to find a way to get the response of a post method executed through headless browser.

```
session = requests.Session()
session.get(<url here)
print session.cookies
r = session.post(url).content
print r
```

The problem is that the response r is full of javascript and I can't use Selenium to execute it because it doesn't support the POST method (as far as I know).
Any ideas?

Comment: Selenium does everything that a browser can do. Including POSTS.
If the page is heavy with Javascript, its better you go with Selenium. Requests won't get you very far for a dynamically generated page.

Answer (score 15):

You can try using [`selenium-requests`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium-requests/):

> Extends Selenium WebDriver classes to include the request function
>   from the Requests library, while doing all the needed cookie and
>   request headers handling.

Example:

```
from seleniumrequests import Firefox

webdriver = Firefox()
response = webdriver.request('POST', 'url here', data={"param1": "value1"})
print(response)
```

Comment: i'm using chrome, and it's didn't works, open 2 tab, and one of them immediately closed, the rest only url filled with text `data;`