# How to do a POST on a webpage to login into the site using selenium-requests with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver

I've to login into a site (for exemple I will use facebook.com). I can manage the login process using selenium, but I need to do it with a POST. I've tried to use requests but I'm not able to pass the info needed to the selenium webdriver in order to enter in the site as logged user. I've found on-line that exists a library that integrates selenium and requests https://pypi.org/project/selenium-requests/ , but the problem is that there is no documentation and I'm blocked in the same story.

With selenium-requests

```
webdriver = Chrome()
url = "https://www.facebook.com"
webdriver.get(url)

params = {
    'email': 'my_email',
    'pass': 'my_password'
    }
resp = webdriver.request('POST','https://www.facebook.com/login/device-based/regular/login/?login_attempt=1&lwv=110', params) 

webdriver.get(url) 
# I hoped that the new page open was the one with me logged in but it did not works
```

With Selenium and requests passing the cookies

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
webdriver = Chrome()
url = "https://www.facebook.com"
driver.get(url)

#storing the cookies generated by the browser
request_cookies_browser = driver.get_cookies()

#making a persistent connection using the requests library
params = {
    'email': 'my_email',
    'pass': 'my_password'
    }

s = requests.Session()
#passing the cookies generated from the browser to the session
c = [s.cookies.set(c['name'], c['value']) for c in request_cookies_browser]
resp = s.post('https://www.facebook.com/login/device-based/regular/login/?login_attempt=1&lwv=110', params) #I get a 200 status_code
#passing the cookie of the response to the browser
dict_resp_cookies = resp.cookies.get_dict()
response_cookies_browser = [{'name':name, 'value':value} for name, value in dict_resp_cookies.items()]
c = [driver.add_cookie(c) for c in response_cookies_browser]
driver.get(url)
```

In both the cases if in the end I print the cookies seems that something as changed from the beginning, but the page remains the one with the login form.

This is the codes I've tried, I put both the attempts but it is sufficient to find the solution to one of these two.
Someone can help me and know what I've to do or to change to open the page with me logged in?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To be honest I don't even understand why you are trying to use Selenium if you want to just interact at the network traffic level, you may as well just use the request library directly and totally cut selenium out of the picture.  Is there a reason you are not interacting with the web page in the normal way?

Comment: Maybe I can use only requests as you suggests, I've started using selenium and I've created the function that come after this, that is a crawler to search some info into the page (the one i reached after the login). Assuming to use only requests can you explain me what I have to do? I mean, I do the post but I do not understand how I can have the page (the HTML can be sufficient) after the login

Comment: Well you aren't really using Selenium.  You are using a library that wraps requests and pretends to be related to selenium when it isn't really.  After getting a reposes from a POST request you just need to look at the response content to get the HTML (https://realpython.com/python-requests/#the-response).  Again I'm unclear what you are actually trying to do though.  Selenium is perfectly appropriate if you want to interact with a web page, your question is implying you don't.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
In your code, you just pass the params as is. 
In [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34964423/selenium-post-method) the code would be `data=params` in :

```
resp = webdriver.request('POST','https://www.facebook.com/login/device-based/regular/login/?login_attempt=1&lwv=110', params)
```